# How to use DistCp to directly convert data into tables in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, distcp

I am using DistCp to copy the data from cluster 1 to cluster 2. I was successfully able to copy the table data from cluster 1 into cluster 2. However, using the hdfs, the data has been sent to file browser.

Is there any direct way to convert this hdfs data into a Hive table (including data type, delimeters ...etc) by use of DistCp command(s)? I can certainly query it to gather the data from hdfs, however I'll have to convert them one-by-one. Trying to look for efficient way to this. Thanks!

Example:

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/source/a hdfs://nn1:8020/source/b hdfs://nn2:8020/destination
```

Comment: you could create an extrenal table at the destination cluster end before hand thats pointing to this hdfs directory

Comment: But I'll have to create it one-by-one. I am looking for hadoop to automatically generate the tables in Hive through the data that has been loaded into HDFS via code above.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't found a documentation where you can directly use DistCp to copy tables. However, if any one is looking for similar situation, they can use. Worked for me.

```
--hive
export table <<<table_name>>> to '<<<hdfs path>>>';

#bash/shell
hadoop distcp source desitination 

--hive
import table <<<table_name>> from '<<<hdfs>>>';
```